# How to use toThrow() with jest

Tags: jestjs

I would like to know why the following code does not work in jest.
I thought Error() automatically throw so it can be omitted

```
expect(() => {
  Error();
}).toThrow();
```

Answer (score 4):

["When Error is used like a function -- without new, it will return an Error object."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Used_as_a_function)

`Error()` creates an `Error` object, but it still needs to be thrown with `throw`:

```js
expect(() => {
  throw Error();
}).toThrow();
```